# I need to add Hebrew and Greek fonts on my Mac air 12.5 Monterey for seminary class

Tags: font

Professor requested that both Greek and Hebrew fonts be loaded to my Mac so I could read them when they pop up in a paper.  Cannot seem to find a method that works.  Is adding a font the same as changing the keyboard?  I do not want to type-just read it.
Sw

Comment: There are Hebrew fonts pre-installed with macOS 12.5 but I wasn't able to find any Greek fonts. Is your professor supplying the fonts or a link to download them?

Comment: Have you tried [importing the font via FontBook](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/font-book/fntbk1000/mac)?

Comment: Get him to send you some examples & see how much of it you can already read.

Comment: MacOS comes with full support for Unicode Greek and hebrew already. Come back here with an example of a text you cannot read. These languages should display just fine already without you having to do anything at all with fonts, unless you are in one of the Bible study courses that still uses legacy non-Uncode Latin-mapped fonts (like Bibleworks) from 30 years ago.  In that latter case, the professor will have to give you the name of the non-standard fonts and where to download them from.

Comment: Agree with @TomGewecke - I thought we were diving far too quickly into 'oooh, get new fonts' territory.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a font is as easy as moving it to the `Fonts` folder inside your user account's `Library` folder.

This folder is sometimes hidden by default, but you can get to it from the Go menu in the Finder.

[image]

If it doesn't show here, hold the Alt key.

Alternatively, you can put the fonts into the Fonts folder in the root-level Library folder (at the top of the disk hierarchy).  This will make the fonts available to all users on the computer.

There are plenty of fonts with Greek and Hebrew characters already installed. Times New Roman, STIX General, Georgia, Baskerville all have Greek characters -- though they may not have the full range of diacritics.
Arial Hebrew, Corsiva Hebrew, New Penimim MT all have Hebrew characters. There may be others. (Noto Sans has variants for pretty much every script ever -- including Egyptian Hieroglyphs and Cuneiform!

If you're asking about how to access those glyphs from the keyboard, then yes, you'll need to change the Input Source, which defines what characters you get when you press the keyboard. You can do this in **System Preferences > Keyboards**.

Here are examples of Unicode Greek and Hebrew (John 1:1 and Genesis 1:1) which you should be able to read on your Mac without any additions:

Ἐν ἀρχῇ ἦν ὁ λόγος

בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ